# Where to save graphics.cfg file

Tags: graphics

following the instructions at http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/build_epsgraphics.html I could manage to get pdflatex to convert eps files into pdf on the fly.

As a test I've saved the graphics.cfg files in the same directory as my test.tex files and would now like to move it into my local tree so that it will be used by default for my other tex documents.

If my local texmf tree is in $HOME/texmf what should be the exact path where to save the graphics.cfg file?
(As you might have guessed I'm using tex-live on a Ubuntu machine)

Thanks a lot for your help,
Cheers, Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anywhere in your tex path so you could make a texmf-local/tex/latex/graphics-cfg directory for example and put it in there, as long as you re-run texhash or whatever it's called these days to rebuild the file path database it should work.