# Multiple graphics.cfg?

Tags: graphics, installing, file-lookup

I'm using tex-live on a Ubuntu machine.
I got a customized graphics.cfg file (configuration file for the graphix package)
that I'd like to use as default on my system.

I've tried to locate the graphics.cfg used on my system:

```
locate graphics.cfg
```

but I got many results:

```
/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/latex-graphics-companion/inputs/graphics.cfg
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc-en/latex/latex-graphics-companion/inputs/graphics.cfg
/usr/share/texlive-base/graphics.cfg
```

Which file should I substitute with the desired one? Thanks for the help

P.s. I know that I might modify the one in my local tree, but I'm writing a tutorial and would like to write a section explaining how to modify it system-wide and user-wide.

Comment: Compile a small document which uses graphicx and then check in the log-file the path of graphics.cfg. But you should really *not* change this one. It can be overwritten by updates. Make a copy in a similar path in another texmf-tree searched before the main tree (this can be one used system-wide).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't think a document is required. `kpsewhich graphics.cfg` does the job nicely. Ok, under Windows a document might be easier for many people.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this different to your other recent question [Where to save graphics.cfg file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55027/2975)? Both is basically the same topic and should be put into one question. Note that you can edit and update your existing questions.

Comment: @Martin Yes `kpsewhich` works too. I didn't point to the log because I thouhgt it simpler or faster but because imho it is vital for a (La)TeX to realize that the log-file contains useful informations. Someone who doesn't know that the log-file contains the path to files obviously never has really looked at the file.

Comment: @MartinScharrer this question is specific for the file used system-wide by tex-live. The other question is about the local three of each user.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the advice, it makes sense.
So how can I create a different tree to be used system-wide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't substitude anything, but place your file at a location where it can be found before the other files. I personally would put it at `~/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg`, but you might not have a local `~/texmf` enabled.

Note that `locate` is the wrong tool for the job. Use TeX's own tool `kpsewhich`. It is the one used by TeX to find it's input files. For example for my installation (Ubuntu with manual install TeX Live) I get:

```
$ kpsewhich graphics.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
```

After you installed your version you can check with `kpsewhich graphics.cfg` if it is taken by TeX or if another is found first.
Note that changes to a TEXMF tree usually requires updating the file database using `mktexlsr` aka. `texhash`. I always do `texhash ~/texmf`, just to be on the safe side.

---

Note that it is even possible to load a different version of the config file if you input it with a specific directory part, i.e. `\input{latexconfig/graphics.cfg}` inside a local `graphics.cfg` would load the original first. You would need to change the `latexconfig` dir to the one of your installation.

Comment: Thanks @Martin incidentally you have answered also my other question about the local tree.